# JAVA JTabbedPane - border of stacked tabs removal

Tags: java, swing, border

I have simple GUI that is supposed to show some informations. I created menu of multiple JTabbedPanes and the tabs are stacking on each other as intended. I am trying to remove borders on left, right and bottom sides of each tab so it doesn't look stacked. I haven't found anything that would solve my problem, is there actually a way to do it?

Thank you for answer in advance.

Here is screen shot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/60L3n.png]

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Convertor implements ItemListener {

public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) throws FileNotFoundException {
    //main panel containing all below
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    //Menu panel
    JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel();
    menuPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1200, 30));
    menuPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1200, 30));
    menuPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200, 30));
    menuPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.weightx = 0;
    gbc.weighty = 0;
    gbc.ipadx = 0;
    gbc.ipady = 0;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);        
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0; 
    mainPanel.add(menuPanel, gbc); 

    //Menu panel buttons
    JButton importButton = new JButton("Import");
    importButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 20));
    menuPanel.add(importButton, BorderLayout.EAST); 
    JButton button2 = new JButton("XXX");
    button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 20));
    menuPanel.add(button2, BorderLayout.EAST); 

    //PAYER PANEL CONTAINER - containing payer panel
    JPanel payerPanelContainer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());    
    //payerPanelContainer.setBackground(Color.RED);
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 0;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.ipadx = 0;
    gbc.ipady = 0;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);        
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1; 
    mainPanel.add(payerPanelContainer, gbc); 

    //PAYER PANEL 
    JPanel payerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());    
    payerPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    payerPanelContainer.add(payerPanel); 

    //PAYER PANEL TABBED PANE
    JTabbedPane payerTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.ipadx = 0;
    gbc.ipady = 0;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);        
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0; 
    payerPanel.add(payerTabbedPane, gbc); 

    //Create payer tabs
    JPanel payerTab1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());       
    payerTabbedPane.addTab("Payer 1", payerTab1);

    JPanel payerTab2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    payerTabbedPane.addTab("Payer 2", payerTab2);

    //create MSISDN tabbed pane in each payer tab
    JTabbedPane msisdnTabbedPane1 = new JTabbedPane();
    payerTab1.add(msisdnTabbedPane1);

    //create MSISDN tabs
    JPanel generalTabPayer1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());       
    msisdnTabbedPane1.addTab("GENERAL", generalTabPayer1);

    JPanel msisdnTab1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());       
    msisdnTabbedPane1.addTab("MSISDN 1", msisdnTab1);

    JPanel msisdnTab2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());       
    msisdnTabbedPane1.addTab("MSISDN 2", msisdnTab2);

    JPanel msisdnTab3 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());       
    msisdnTabbedPane1.addTab("MSISDN 2", msisdnTab3);

    //create MSISDN options tabbed pane
    JTabbedPane msisdnOptionsTabbedPane1 = new JTabbedPane();
    msisdnTab1.add(msisdnOptionsTabbedPane1);

    //create MSISDN options tabs
    JPanel msisdnOptionsTab1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());       
    msisdnOptionsTabbedPane1.addTab("Option 1", msisdnOptionsTab1);

    JPanel msisdnOptionsTab2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());       
    msisdnOptionsTabbedPane1.addTab("Option 2", msisdnOptionsTab2);

    //add main panel to window
    pane.add(mainPanel);

}


private static void createAndShowGUI() throws FileNotFoundException {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("CSV Reader");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    Convertor demo = new Convertor();
    demo.addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(1206, 800); 
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1206, 800));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1206, 800));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {            
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                createAndShowGUI();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but it's hard. The only way to do it is to provide your own UI for the tabbed pane. Here is the example, which is not completly satisfied your requirements, but it can show the way, which you must go (sorry, but I cann't provide a complete solution, because it could be time expansive).

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalTabbedPaneUI;


public class BorderlessTabsExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(MetalLookAndFeel.class.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Nothing
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new BorderlessTabsExample());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JTabbedPane tabber = new JTabbedPane();
        tabber.addTab("First", new JLabel("First"));
        tabber.addTab("Second", new JLabel("Second"));
        tabber.addTab("Third", new JLabel("Third"));
        // set the UI which will paint your tabs
        tabber.setUI(new MetalBorderlessTabbedPaneUI()); 
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Tabber test");
        frm.add(tabber);
        frm.setSize(500, 400);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class MetalBorderlessTabbedPaneUI extends MetalTabbedPaneUI {

        @Override
        protected void installDefaults() {
            super.installDefaults();
            if (contentBorderInsets != null) {
                contentBorderInsets = new Insets(contentBorderInsets.top, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintContentBorderRightEdge(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, int selectedIndex, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintContentBorderBottomEdge(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, int selectedIndex, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintContentBorderLeftEdge(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, int selectedIndex, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
            // Do nothing
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunatelly that's not exactly what I am looking for.
From your example I can see removed borders from around the tab name, what I want to do is to remove borders from the content area with upper border left as it is for readibility, I tried to apply your solution to mine and the result was as I described above.

Comment: @EduardFarkaš Please provide a second screen, that shows what you try to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to get rid of these: https://gyazo.com/adc0bea5fc6639e70a549ded2e367ff7

Comment: @EduardFarkaš I've corrected my example. Please check whether it works better for you.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, this solution is closer but it isn't the desired result. It removed the borders in a way, that there is no black line, but the "shift" itself is still there. 
I don't know how to say it another way, but I would like to achieve 100% content area on 3rd level tab. Meaning that 100% of window width will be accessible for content. Here is what i got with implementation of your solution: https://gyazo.com/1861a2ac8ca90119aadb7d3c81b06e87

Comment: @EduardFarkaš I've modified my example again. Now the "shift" should be removed.

Comment: exactly what I needed, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @EduardFarkaš Please mark my answer as solution for your question (click on white checkmark). This will give for me and you some reputation points.